# O que "android.R.id.content" significa?

Tags: android

Estou seguindo um tutorial aqui e ele faz referência a isso nessa linha:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
```

Qual o significado deste identificador?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explicação:** O `android.R.id.content` É uma constante que tem o valor de um número Inteiro, que é o endereço referenciado a tal conteúdo, que está declarado em `R.java` que é um arquivo que é gerado toda vez que você der Build no projeto.

**Explicação do `content`em si:**

`android.R.id.content` - É um numero inteiro usado para referenciar ou identificar o elemento usado como base de sua `View`.

A cada elemento que você criar, você terá um endereço para ele no `R.java`, este `android.R.id.content` é apenas uma maneira mais facil de referenciar ao seu elemento.

Também é utilizado `android.R.layout.nomedolayout` para referenciar Layouts em XML em sua aplicação.

Eles são Resources da sua aplicação, por isso ficam na pasta `res` do seu projeto Assim como há outros:

`android.R.strings.nomedastring` - para strings cadastradas em `res/values/strings.xml`
`android.R.color.nomedacor` - para cores cadastradas em `res/values/colors.xml`
`android.R.attr.nomedoatributo` - para atributos declarados em `res/values/attrs.xml`
`android.R.style.nomedoestilo` - para estilos que estão em `res/values/styles.xml`

**Detalhes:**

As strings são utilizadas para reutilizar a mesma string para vários locais, ou também para alterar apenas um lugar quando quiser alterar um padrão, como por exemplo um título que é usado em todas as `Activity`'s do seu projeto, voce deseja altera-lo e para não ter que alterar em todos os `Layout`'s você usa uma string no `Layout` e depois basta alterar ela no `Strings.xml`

Color's tem o mesmo objetivo como as strings mas seriam, no caso, cores.

Attr's, são atributos, porém consistem com o mesmo objetivo.

Styles são usados para criar temas e modificar estilos padrões do Android para componentes do Android.

Essas propriedades citadas, são utilizadas no Visual de sua `Activity` ou seja, no `Layout`.

Obs: Os layouts ficam em `res/layout`.

Comment: Obrigado! Acho que não fui específico o bastante. Minha dúvida é quanto ao android.R.id.content exatamente. Não sei o que é o "content".

Comment: Bom, achei que isto fosse meio óbvio, desculpe, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Entendi, e marquei como resposta. Valeu!

Comment: Disponha, eu que agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

É o valor da *root view*. "android." não é utilizado para referenciar `resources` do próprio app. Para seus próprios `resources`, utilize apenas `R.`, não `android.R`.

Answer (score -2):

O `android.R.id.content` e um identificador genérico para o elemento root da view.